# How to set borders between children from parent in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For setting a border line **between** elements, I use border on one side for each child, *except the last one*. For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zhhkh/)

```
<div class="parent">
   <div>First</div>
   <div>Second</div>
   <div>Third</div>
   <div>Fourth</div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
.parent div{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom:dashed 1px #000}
.parent div:last-child{
    border-bottom:dashed 0 #000
}
```

Is there a way to set the border between children from parent's CSS style? without using `last-child`. In other words, in one single statement from parent rule.

Comment: No, the border is a property of the child element, and thus can only be specified on them.

Comment: @Barney: That's the answer.

Comment: @Barney I do not mean border, any possible solution. I am curious if there is a property in CSS to deal with inner place of child elements.

Comment: there is the `nth-child()` selector but this doesn't work in IE (no surprise there!)

Comment: The same is true of any property. It's not that `border` is the property in question, it's that properties are properties! Some properties are inherited (`color` and `font` are for example, `border` isn't), but you would still need to raise the exception for the `last-child` with these. For syntactic ease, a CSS-precompiler like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) could help, but CSS doesn't allow that kind of rule-setting.

Comment: @Barney, This is just play with selectors. Both solutions suggested by you and BoltClock are useful and what I was looking for. Let's the selector take care of it!

Comment: @All I'm just explaining the CSS logic in response to your property-related comment — I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the border is a property of the child element, and thus can only be specified on them. You can use a single rule for this, but it requires advanced CSS3 selector support:

```
.parent > div:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom: dashed 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: Support for `:not()` and `:last-child` is identical across all browsers, but for a CSS2 solution you can use `.parent > div + div { border-top: dashed 1px #000; }`

Comment: @BoltClock you suggested this answer out of comment. Why not posting your solution as an answer, it is a practical solution.

Comment: @All: No need - if I post an answer I'd only end up repeating what Barney has already explained.

Answer (score 0):

I just know a workaround: use jQuery and iterate through those child elements(each: http://api.jquery.com/each/) and set your css class if next(next: http://api.jquery.com/?s=next) element is also child...

I think another way, just using css does not exist, but I'm not sure, if you find a solution with css only, please post it ;)

Greetings

Comment: The OP already has a CSS solution, and is asking for a simpler one. Involving Javascript and jQuery makes the solution more complex.

Comment: absolutely right, css solution and my comment were made nearly the same time... Sorry for this...